# Str is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to decrypt a text file which I have recently encrypted using a piece of code I created which works perfectly,
to be able to decrypt my code I need to find out what the offset factor was from my previously shown 8 digit character key and when the user inputs this it is completely fine and this part of the code works fine. so I have calculated my offset factor and when I go to change my characters into integers to minus the offset to then convert back to a character I am faced with a message that reads

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   
>  File "N:\4512_CB4-Traditional Application\Encryption,Decrption coursework.py", line 154, in  MainMenu()
>     
>  File "N:\4512_CB4-Traditional Application\Encryption,Decrption coursework.py", line 22, in MainMenu
>       Decrypt()
>     
>  File "N:\4512_CB4-Traditional Application\Encryption,Decrption coursework.py", line 135, in Decrypt
>       y=chr(x)
>   
>  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

This is my code:

```
def Decrypt():
Message=[]
Character=[]
for chr in Decry:
    A = (ord(chr))
    Character.append(A)
c = sum(Character)
c = round(c/8)
c = c - 32

print("\n" *1)
print('Starting Decryption')
count = 0
while count !=len(info):
    Message.append(info[count])
    count=count+1
count = 0
while count!=len(info):
    if Message[count] == " ":
        count=count+1
    else:
        x=ord(Message[count])
        x=x-c
        if x <33:
            x=x+94
            y=chr(x)
            Message[count]=y
            count=count+1
        else:
            y=chr(x)
            Message[count]=y
            count=count+1
print("...Decryption finished...")
time.sleep(1)
file=",".join(Message).replace(",","")
print('This is your new text file')
print(file)
filename = input('what would you like your file to be saved as')+'.txt'
openfile = open (filename, 'w')
thedetails =openfile.write(file)
time.sleep(1)
print('Done!')
```

Comment: You have shadowed `chr` functon by doing `for chr in Decry:`. Last loop variable value leaks to global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have overwritten the `chr` function by using it as a variable at the top of the code. So rename that variable and it should work fine.

To clarify, the snippet below is where this happens beyond this `for` loop Python will handle `chr` as a variable instead of the built-in function it used to be.

```
for chr in Decry:
    A = (ord(chr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `chr` in the `for` loop:

```
for chr in Decry:
  A = (ord(chr))
```

with some other name. It is creating a conflict with the inbuilt function `chr`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively just create a copy of chr like this:

```
     def copyofchr(**args):
         chr(**args)
```

now always when you used `chr()` for something, replace it by `copyofchr()`
You now need to implement this tiny code on the top after your Decrypt() function, it will work.

Yours sincerely heureka